# Autoformat code in Eclipse when entering semicolon or brace

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Coming from Visual Studio, I'm used to getting my code auto-formatted whenever I enter a semicolon or a closing curly brace. Is it possible to do the same with Eclipse in the JavaScript editor?

Comment: Are you sure you mean JavaScript? I thought Eclipse was just Oracle's Java. There is a difference.

Comment: Eclipse also can work with C++, for example.

Comment: @SeanKenny: Yes, I mean JavaScript. I have installed the JavaScript editor from the JavaScript Development Tools (of the Web Developer Tools).

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  to select your code, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, this will make code indentation properly for javascript code in eclipse kepler.

Comment: That's an interesting workaround, but is it possible to configure Eclipse to do this automatically when the programmer ends a statement or block with a semicolon or a closing brace as Tobias asks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the JavaScript plugin but I'm assuming it works the same such that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> formats selected code to the correct indentation. I hope this is what you mean by formatting. Not too familiar with JavaScript so unsure of the best format.

Example, in Java:

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
boolean format = false;
if (format) {
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
System.out.println("Hello World" + i);
}
}
}
```

Goes to:

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    boolean format = false;
    if (format) {
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello World" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the key binds for eclipse in Window > Preferences > General > Keys > Correct Indentation

Comment: CTRL-I doesn't seem to do anything in JavaScript. CTRL-SHIFT-F does the auto-formatting which I mean and what you have shown. However, I don't want to press the extra key combination for it. I want it to happen automatically whenever I end a line of code by pressing ; or }.

Comment: That doesn't help much: Should I bind "}" and ";" to "Correct Indentation"? I don't think that would work. If Eclipse supports it - which I hardly doubt in the meanwhile - it would be an option to select somewhere and nothing with key binding.

Comment: When writing Java, typing { then hitting enter makes the matching } with a line in between at the correct indentation. Also, hitting enter after a ; starts the next line at the same indentation as the one above. I'm not sure why this isn't working for the JavaScript. I use a gaming keyboard with G keys left of tab, I have those bound for commonly used functions like Correct Indentation, Quick Fix and Code Assist. Although I'm not entirely sure why pressing `Ctrl + Shift + F` every so often is all that bad.

Comment: Ok, it's not just the indentation I'm looking for, but the whole formatting. E.g. if I write "int sum=a+b;" I want that after hitting the ";" the line gets formatted to "int sum = a + b;" (note the spaces in between). In order to do this, I would currently have to manually select the whole line and then press CTRL-SHIFT-F. Of course I could do this, but it would be nice if that worked automatically.

Comment: Odd, for me, pressing `Ctrl + Shift + F` does that. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @SeanKenny I think the question is not "how to format my document". It's "how to format as I type without having to call the format document macro". I want the same since I use VS all the time and it formats automatically as you type. It's a great time saver. So, is there any way to get Eclipse to do this?

Comment: @JoshM.: Just for your information, until now I did not find any solution for that. I think that currently it's not possible with Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

You can get autoformatting for javascript :

```
right click project > javascript > code style > formatter
```

You may have to make sure it has a project facet of javascript, I can't remember if that is necessary.

Comment: I have no JavaScript entry in the project properties; however, I have them in the global preferences. But where can I configure that everytime I key in a ; or }, the auto-formatting is done?